# Magento 2.3.4 version. how to change product wise title tag header?

Tags: magento, tags, product, title

How can I change the Title tag in header dynamically product wise? My magento version is 2.3.4.i'm using free template https://demo4techies.com/preview/?template=M2HTNEX .

Comment: Please show what you have already tried. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask